# Mandating file headers

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-2015, pylint

I am a newbie to Python.

We are using Visual Studio as the IDE and github for code control.

What we want to be able to do assign a default header to each file and make it a mandate.

For example:

If anyone starts a new file, it should create one with the following header:

```
"""
Name: <current_owner>
Last Modified: <time when the code was modified, being updated with every commit:
"""
```

As obvious, "Last Modified:" should get updated automatically with every commit.

Comment: Yikes, this information is already in your CVS (Git/SVN/whatever). Why do you want this cluttered in your source code?

Comment: Why? You're using git, so the name/time information is redundant (see man page of `git-blame`, `git-log`, etc.).  I don't think it's necessary to put them in the source file at all.

Comment: It may be done by using post-commit hooks, but really, don't. There is no guarantee that hooks are enabled on all dev machines. As a result, comments would rot and go out-to-date regularly. Stick to capabilities git is providing you.

Comment: I think I used wrong example above. I wanted to attach email IDs one of the tags: "Owner: -CORETECH@MY_COMPANY.com-". Eventually, when we run automated tests due off hrs, we would want to send an email to the entire group as opposed to a specific individual.